# How to set association class_name based on model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rails-activerecord

I have the following models:

```
class Schematic < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :branch, foreign_key: :location_cd
  has_many :schematics_stocks, class_name: 'SchematicsStock', dependent: :destroy
end

class SchematicsStock < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :schematic
  belongs_to :stock, foreign_key: "stock_no"
end

class Stock < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'stockslc'
  self.primary_key = 'stock_no'
  has_one :schematics_stock
end
```

There are various stock tables (stockslc, stockalb, etc.) based on the location_cd (slc, alb, etc.) of the schematic. Is there some way I can do schematic.schematics_stocks[0].stock and have it automatically choose the right stock table?

I thought about creating a model for each stock table. In the SchematicsStock class I could do

```
Object.const_get("Stock#{schematic.location_cd.downcase}").find(stock_no)
```

but this would query the database for every stock no, whereas previously it only did one db call for all the schematics.

I looked into [ActiveRecord association extensions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions) to see if I could define a belongs_to stock method based on the location_cd at the same time schematics_stocks is defined. Something like

```
class Schematic < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :branch, foreign_key: :location_cd
  has_many :schematics_stocks, class_name: 'SchematicsStock', dependent: :destroy do
    belongs_to stock, class_name: "Stock#{location_cd.downcase}"
  end
end
```

This looks like a perfect opportunity to use [Postgresql table partioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html) where I could partition a stock table based on the location_cd, but changing the stock schema isn't an option and the there is already a lot of production data in the other tables.

I have code like the following in my view.

```
  <% @schematic.schematics_stocks.includes(:stock)
    .order(:stock_no).each do |s_stock| %>
```

I am trying to decide if I should just write a query to get it from the correct table and then rewrite my view code or if there is a way to keep my view code the same.

Comment: use sti or use polymorphic option

Comment: Are you allowed to update `location_cd` values for any table? I'll use [Rails polymorphic associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) but it requires `location_cd` values to have a specific string format: that is it should be camelised & capitalized, but the values you currently have are `stockslc`, and `stockalb`, all of which are downcased (and presumably underscore-format?). Now this is not really a problem except that you cannot define constants starting with downcase, so you cannot have a model named:

Comment: ... `class stockslc < ApplicationRecord`, which will throw an error. Unfortunately, looking around, I don't think there's a way to have customised-format that you can set in Rails to evaluate `location_cd` mappings to model.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following is a workound, if you just want to be efficient with SQL?

```
class Schematic < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :schematic_stocks, dependent: :destroy

  def stocks
    # say if `location_cd` == 'alb', then
    # you'll need to create a model named Stockalb in your app/models
    # and a model for each "stock table" you have.
    stock_class = ('Stock' + location_cd).constantize
    stock_class.joins(:schematic_stocks)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I could set the model's table_name at runtime. Initially I used the following code to use the correct stock table

```
<% Stock.table_name = "stock" + @schematic.location_cd.downcase %>
<% @schematic.schematics_stocks.includes(:stock)
  .order(:stock_no).each do |s_stock| %>
```

Based on [Jay-Ar Polidario's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57502912/how-to-set-association-class-name-based-on-model-attribute/57509096#57509096), I decided to make a method in the schematic model to change the table_name.

```
# schematic.rb
def schematics_stocks_with_stocks
  Stock.table_name = 'stock' + location_cd.downcase
  schematics_stocks.includes(:stock)
end

# view 
<% @schematic.schematics_stocks_with_stocks
  .order(:stock_no).each do |s_stock| %>
```

Comment: I was just looking back at my past answers, and I just wanted to let you know that I don't think setting the table name via `Stock.table_name = ...` is thread-safe. On the rare instance that two or more threads(i.e 2 requests) concurrently try to set `Stock.table_name = ...`,then the 2nd thread would have overriden the value and the 1st thread then would fail. This would veeery rarely happen though! The two threads need to run at exactly almost the same time. If you are using multi-thread server like `puma`, then this risk exists. But if single-threaded like `unicorn`, then you should be fine.